# what function should I use in Processing using Minim library for changing the volume, and speed rate of a music?

Tags: processing, minim

I'm creating a virtual DJ using processing with Blob detection. I need to change the volume of the song and the rate of the song using the blob detection. I used sound library, it worked very well, but I found that I need to use Minim Library for giving more functionality to the project. However, minim and sound library don't work together so I only have to use of of them. I use setVolume() and setGain() it did not work. what should I use?

Comment: Please be more specific than saying it didn't work. Please post a [mcve] that we can run. Note that this should not be your full project. It should be a simple example program that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

user setGain() (or shiftGain()), but try a larger number (number's between 0-1 won't have any effect)